# The words men, ben and pen in Kazakh

Tags: vowels, vowel-harmony

I came across this problem where the difference between men, ben and pen in the Kazakh language was asked. I understand it has something to do with Vowel harmony, but I did not quite understand it.
Any help would be appreciated.

If it helps, here is a link to the question:
http://www.ioling.org/problems/sample/i1/

Comment: Please tell us the whole question here - don't just link to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-ben: after z, ž

-pen: after unvoiced consonants and b, d, g, v

-men: after vowels, sonorants and possessive forms (the latter is irrelevant here)

Source (in Russian): http://kaz-tili.kz/su_tvorit.htm

Consonant assimilation in suffixes is as typical of Turkic languages as vowel harmony.